# Get the all Firebase nodes data and apply some conditions on it and show the results on a ListActivity: Error?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Actually I am creating an Android app and I have saveed the data on Firebase Database and When I am trying to retrieve that data and want to show some selected data on ListActivity and it says Unfortunately the app has stopped working.

My code is:

```
public class SearchResults extends ListActivity {

    public ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseReference ref =
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adp);

    }

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot Snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : Snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String u, p, mixUP;
                if (snapshot.child("post").getValue(Integer.class) == 1) {

            u =(String)snapshot.child("Username").getValue(String.class);
            p =(String)snapshot.child("phoneNumber").getValue(String.class);
            mixUP = "Name: " + u + "        phone: " + p;
            data.add(mixUP.trim());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //handle databaseError
            Toast.makeText(SearchResults.this, "Data Retrived failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

please Help me to resolve this kind of Issue Please correct it the way I retrieve data from Firebase and overall code to accomplish the task..
Thanks in advance.

My Logcat is:

ethod cen.setExtras, referenced from method cea.setExtras
02-28 21:00:51.468 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18951: Lcen;.setExtras (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
02-28 21:00:51.468 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
02-28 21:00:51.508 11443-11443/? W/Gmail: EasBundling:in EasBundling.init, isBundlingEnabled=true
02-28 21:00:51.518 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.accounts.AccountManager.removeAccountExplicitly, referenced from method ebd.a
02-28 21:00:51.518 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7814: Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;.removeAccountExplicitly (Landroid/accounts/Account;)Z
02-28 21:00:51.518 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0011
02-28 21:00:51.538 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.accounts.AccountManager.removeAccountExplicitly, referenced from method ebd.a
02-28 21:00:51.538 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7814: Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;.removeAccountExplicitly (Landroid/accounts/Account;)Z
02-28 21:00:51.538 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a
02-28 21:00:51.659 636-1019/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=11443, uid=10057 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method ld.a
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8537: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method ld.b
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8533: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method ld.b
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8555: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method ld.c
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8532: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
02-28 21:00:51.679 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
02-28 21:00:51.699 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method hgm.a
02-28 21:00:51.699 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8543: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
02-28 21:00:51.699 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
02-28 21:00:51.789 636-959/? E/BatteryStatsImpl: slot=0 bin=4 CurSlotRaw=0
02-28 21:00:51.799 2462-2816/? W/Icing: isOptedInForAppHistory: empty Account Name encountered
02-28 21:00:51.839 2462-2816/? I/Icing: Performing maintenance usage 2272204 budget 466052582 free 99.512% index free 99.591% purge? false target 326236807
02-28 21:00:51.849 11443-11443/? W/GAV2: Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
02-28 21:00:51.849 636-1018/? D/ActivityManager: startService callerProcessName:com.google.android.gms, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gms
02-28 21:00:51.889 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.PowerManager.isInteractive, referenced from method kau.onActivityPaused
02-28 21:00:51.889 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9728: Landroid/os/PowerManager;.isInteractive ()Z
02-28 21:00:51.889 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0021
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: wifi: VISIBLE sig=2130837966 act=2130837946
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: mMobileDataState=-1 mMobileDataState2=0
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: apply() mSeparateMobileGroup=8
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: wifi: VISIBLE sig=2130837966 act=2130837946
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: mMobileDataState=-1 mMobileDataState2=0
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: apply() mSeparateMobileGroup=8
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: wifi: VISIBLE sig=2130837966 act=2130837946
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: mMobileDataState=-1 mMobileDataState2=0
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: apply() mSeparateMobileGroup=8
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: wifi: VISIBLE sig=2130837966 act=2130837946
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: mMobileDataState=-1 mMobileDataState2=0
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/SignalClusterView_dual: apply() mSeparateMobileGroup=8
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController_dual: mMobileLabelViews start
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController_dual: mMobileLabelViews set mobileLabel[SIM_0] =Ufone
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController_dual: mMobileLabelViews GONE
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController_dual: mMobileLabelViews2 set mobileLabel[SIM_1] =No service
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController_dual: mMobileLabelViews2 GONE
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController_dual: mSingleMobileLabelViews set : simMode = 1
02-28 21:00:51.909 803-803/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController_dual: mSingleMobileLabelViews set as slot1`s
02-28 21:00:51.939 636-959/? D/ActivityManager: bindService callerProcessName:com.google.android.gm, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gm, action: null
02-28 21:00:52.019 636-985/? D/ActivityManager: startService callerProcessName:com.google.android.gm, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gm
02-28 21:00:52.079 636-9244/? D/ActivityManager: bindService callerProcessName:android, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gsf.login, action: android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator
02-28 21:00:52.079 636-646/? D/ActivityManager: bindService callerProcessName:android, calleePkgName: com.google.android.gsf.login, action: android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator
02-28 21:00:52.099 2462-2816/? I/Icing: Flash index sort hb 43 prefix-hits 162 -> 162 at 45.074ms
02-28 21:00:52.109 636-1134/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gm.exchange/com.android.exchange.service.EasService } U=0: not found
02-28 21:00:52.119 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.AppOpsManager.permissionToOp, referenced from method lq.a
02-28 21:00:52.119 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 8047: Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;.permissionToOp (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
02-28 21:00:52.119 11443-11443/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x001c
02-28 21:00:52.119 11443-11443/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method lq.a
02-28 21:00:52.119 11443-11443/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8550: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: Unfortunately the app has stopped working with what error?

Comment: Error Means Problem please resolve this oR have another suggestion to do the task

Comment: Paste here the entire error from your logcat.

Comment: ok Boss Wait a while